# It seems that std::flush doesn't work with std::cout

Tags: c++, netbeans-7, iostream

Just a simple test:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int , char** ) 
{
  for( size_t i = 0; i < 1000; i++ )
  {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
  }
  std::cout << std::flush;
  return 0;
}
```

I expect :

```
...
997
998
999
```

But I get :

```
...
838
839
840
```

Please, tell me what I'm doing wrong?
How does std::flush works with std::cout exactly?
Thanks in advance.

PS

Environment: Ubuntu Linux, g++ 4.8, launched from NetBeans 7.2
I can not reproduce it from shell directly.
May it be a NetBeans bug?

Comment: [Is that your real code](http://ideone.com/W1OYiM)? AFAIK, the stream should be flushed anyway when you insert `std::endl`.

Comment: That flush is entirely redundant, as `std::endl` flushes anyway.

Comment: `May it be a NetBeans bug?` I would tend to believe so

Comment: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=222237

Comment: "I can not reproduce it from shell directly." So obviously it is flushed.